# Can a child node have an information gain that is greater than the entropy of the parent?

Tags: classification

I feel like the answer to this question is an obvious "no," but I wanted to get an answer from people who definitely know more about this than I.

Mostly asking because I'm curious about there being a way to speed up the decision tree building process. For example, if my parent node has an entropy of 0.97 and the entropy of the child node is 0. Then my equation for info gain would be:

$$
gain = 0.97- {n_i\over n}(0) = 0.97 
$$

So, in this case, the information gain is equal to the entropy of the parent, so I can't think of anyway for any other attribute to be better for the next split. Am I wrong with this line of thinking? The only time I can think of this being an issue is if the gain is greater than the parent entropy (which I can't see how that would be possible) or for their to be another attribute with equal gain (which would make it an equally valid choice).

Comment: You are right, the answer is 'no'. Entropy function gives always a number greater or equal with $0$. Because of that you cannot get an information gain greater that the parent entropy.